# Why IntelliJ doesn't recognize my main method?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have:

```
fun Array<String>.main() {
  println("Hello World")
}
```

I can compile and run it with 'java main.Main -cp [kotlin-runtime]' but in IntelliJ there isn't a 'run' button, and I cannot select this file as a main file.

#### Edit

It's now correctly recognized by IntelliJ since Kotlin 1.1.5.

Comment: Because you are using the wrong syntax. See [this tutorial](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40701079). What you have done is valid syntax; you defined the `main` function as an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) on `Array<String>`, but this is not what you meant to do. What you want instead is a regular function which takes an `Array<String>` as a parameter.

Comment: The underlying issue is now fixed and should be available in 1.1.5 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18083

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use top-level main function instead

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

Extension function (with any name) for array doesn't work as main method

Comment: You are right, this is valid java class with main method, just because it compiles to:

`public final class MainKt {
  public static final void main(java.lang.String[]);
}`


But Idea supports only common top-level main function

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Nice find :D I've opened an issue on Kotlin's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18083

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, there's only two kinds of main method can be identified by IntelliJ:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
}
fun main(vararg args: String) {
}
```